# bash fork error (Resource temporarily unavailable) does not stop, and keeps showing up every time I try to kill/reboot

Tags: linux, bash, process, fork, ulimit

I mistakenly used a limited server as an iperf server for 5000 parallel connections. (limit is 1024 processes)
Now every time I log in, I see this:

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Then, I try to kill them, but when I do ps, I get this:

```
-bash-4.1$ ps
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Same happens when I do a killall or similar things. 
I have even tried to reboot the system but again this is what I get after reboot:

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo reboot
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash-4.1$
```

So Basically I cannot do anything. all the commands get this error :/
I can, however, do "exit".

This is an off-site server that I do not have physical access to, so I cannot turn it off/on physically.

Any ideas how I can fix this problem? I highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you maybe call someone on-site to reboot the machine for you?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that actually, but it looks like I'll have to do it :sigh:

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given that you can login, you may want to try using `exec` to execute all your commands. After executing `exec` you will have to log in again, since `exec` will kill your shell (by replacing it with the command you run).

`exec` won't take up an extra process slot because it will replaces the running shell with the program to run. Thus, it should be able to bypass the `ulimit` restriction.

Comment: try `exec sudo -s`. Maybe the limit is per-user, and the superuser will be allowed to create more processes.

Comment: Thanks guys! I changed the noproc limit to more using exec, then I rebooted the system using exec! It worked, so at least I don't have to physically go there to reboot!

Comment: Not able to do first level login itself. How to resolve this ?

Comment: @Mona: If you can't log in _and_ you don't have any open sessions, you're probably in a bit of a bind. The easiest thing to do would be to use an external method of power-cycling the box (e.g. use a web console to reboot it or call someone at the data center).

Comment: @nneonneo I did a reset.. Now its resolved. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue recently. In my case the reason was there was code that was executing under my ownership and consumed almost all the resources leaving nothing for my commands. Here's what I did, 
"exec top" to identify the PID thats consuming maximum resources 
"exec kill -9 " killing the PID identified by above command.

After killing the PID, everything came back to normal and I was able to login back.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @DanielVérité 1.) Did you really read my post ? I did not ask any question, I answered the question to best of my knowledge with an example that I underwent. I have no interest in gaining any repuation or attension.

Comment: @YMD: The comment above is canned text from stackoverflow review queue, as opposed to written by me personally. I think your answer was flagged because it's essentially the same as the other answer and I agreed to that (a new answer should be significantly different). Sorry if the boilerplate text comes across as weird, that's more or less [a known problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829)